# Friction problem when object is constrained

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

> [image]
>
> A $60 \;\text{N}$ force is acting on an object of mass $10 \;\text{kg}$ which is placed against a wall touching it. What is the normal force $N$ applied by the wall?

My method: Since the object cannot move in such condition the net electromagnetic forces between the surfaces in contact is perpendicular. So I can say that there is no friction being applied. So simply $N$ is $60 \;\text{N}$.

My teacher's method: He assumed that if there was no wall the $F_{net}$ will be in the right direction with magnitude $10 N$.
$$F_{friction}=N\mu=100\times0.5 = 50\;\text{N} \;\text{to the left}$$
$$F_{net}=60\;\text{N} - 50\;\text{N} = 10\;\text{N} \;\text{to the right}$$

So for acceleration= $0$, a $N$ of magnitude $10\;\text{N}$ must act in left direction.
Considering this, one can also say that the friction can take any value less than $50\;\text{N}$ and the normal force will be $60 \;\text{N}$ minus that value.

Who is right?

Comment: "Considering this, one can also say that the friction can take any value less than $50N$ and the normal force will be 60 minus that value" What makes you think you can arbitrarily change the frictioal force?

Comment: I consider $\mu$ as a static frictional coefficient, which is a self-adjusting force, so it may have any value between range  $0\,N$ to $50\,N$.

Comment: You're almost right , the answer is $10N$ to the Left

Comment: @KeshavSingh Please give any suitable explanation and how is my explanation incorrect.

Comment: See there is a Force of $60N$ to the right and there is a frictional force to the left of $50N$ . So , the resultant force must be to the right of magnitute of $10N$ to the right ........... but you want the value of Normal force by the wall which wil be opposite to the direction of net force on the Object

Comment: @KeshavSingh I already said. Static friction is a self-adjusting force. A similar body at rest isolated on the ground will have no friction because there is no net force on the body. And I am saying what if that $60\,N$ is balanced with equal normal then net force will be 0 hence friction will be $0$.

Comment: Thats a Good Point

Comment: @KeshavSingh I am sorry but are you thinking that the body is moving?

Comment: Oh Sorry , I was not careful . I was thinking of something else . Yeah the Normal will $60N$ cuz there'll be no friction ........ I mean there'll be friction but It won't bother the Forces as the Objcet is fixed to a point

Comment: @BobD I don't quite get what you mean by "Even if the wall wasn't there the maximum possible static friction force of 50 N would not be exceeded by the applied 60 N force." If the wall wasn't there the net force would be 10 N to the right, wouldn't it?

Comment: I'm confused ............... I love this Question tho

Comment: @noah thats what I was saying

Comment: this might be the case $ma=F-f-N$ .cuz even for a static object friction is there .

Comment: The whole question is about which acts first, or *more immediate*, the static friction by the floor or the resistance by the wall, which really goes into how these forces come about microscopically.

Comment: @noah Right. I transposed 50N an 60N in my head

Comment: @user9339131, in my opinion, the normal force is 60 N to the left.  However, the problem as posed is probably indeterminate, as there is no way to determine what fraction of the leftward force is due to friction and what fraction is due to normal force from the wall.  Your teacher shouldn't assign problems like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is tricky in that the idealizations make it not totally clear what the correct answer should be, so this is an ill-posed problem. In the real world, there is nothing like instantaneous forces and infinitely stiff bodies. Pushing on the object will internally deform it and make it lean over to the wall without breaking contact with the floor; the exact distribution of forces between the friction from the floor and the resistance of the wall will depend on the microscopic parameters of the bodies and surfaces involved.